# C++, copy set to vector

Tags: c++, copy, stdvector, stdset

I need to copy `std::set` to `std::vector`:

```
std::set <double> input;
input.insert(5);
input.insert(6);

std::vector <double> output;
std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin()); //Error: Vector iterator not dereferencable
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: there is also `assign()` function: `output.assign(input.begin(), input.end());`

Comment: your vector is empty. There are a multitude of ways to remedy that though as people are pointing out below.

Comment: @Gene: assign() wants to reserve() the necessary amount of storage ahead of time. It will use the input iterators to determine how much is needed, unless the iterators are strictly InputIterator, in which case it will skip reserving and result in reallocations on every push_back(). On the opposite end of the spectrum, BiderectionalIterators would allow it to just subtract end - begin. std::set's iterators, however, are neither (they are  ForwardIterator), and that's unfortunate: in this case, assign() will just walk the entire set to determine its size -- bad performance on large sets.

Answer (score 243):

You need to use a `back_inserter`:

```
std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output));
```

`std::copy` doesn't add elements to the container into which you are inserting:  it can't; it only has an iterator into the container.  Because of this, if you pass an output iterator directly to `std::copy`, you must make sure it points to a range that is at least large enough to hold the input range.

`std::back_inserter` creates an output iterator that calls `push_back` on a container for each element, so each element is inserted into the container.

Alternatively, you could have created a sufficient number of elements in the `std::vector` to hold the range being copied:

```
std::vector<double> output(input.size());
std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin());
```

Or, you could use the `std::vector` range constructor:

```
std::vector<double> output(input.begin(), input.end());
```

Comment: Hi James, instead of your std::copy line (the first code block in your answer), couldn't I just do `output.insert(output.end(), input.begin(), input.end());` instead?

Comment: or just use the cbegin and cend version: `output.insert(output.cend(), input.cbegin(), input.cend());` What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: Should I output.reserve(input.size()); by myself or can I hope that some compiler does it for me?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion) **1)** _"std::copy doesn't add elements..."_ ->here, "add" means literally "add"(e.g. push_back), i.e. incrementing the number of elements of the container. So it's different from modifying the already existing element. **2)** As mentioned in this answer, `std::back_inserter` constructs an iterator that uses `push_back`, so the container must have `push_back` as a member function (eg `std::back_inserter(some_set)` doesn't work, since `std::set` doesn't have `push_back`).

Comment: @AlexisWilke Your example using `reserve` does not work. The vector initialization of this answer is appropriate. As mentioned in this answer, `std::copy` does _not_ "append" or "push_back", contrary to your comment.

Answer (score 151):

Just use the constructor for the vector that takes iterators:

```
std::set<T> s;

//...

std::vector v( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

Assumes you just want the content of s in v, and there's nothing in v prior to copying the data to it.

Answer (score 53):

here's another alternative using `vector::assign`:

```
theVector.assign(theSet.begin(), theSet.end());
```

Comment: That works, but as @SergeyShevchenko commented at the q., this might want to repeatedly reallocate the vector, as it grows, while iterating through the set.

Answer (score 27):

You haven't reserved enough space in your vector object to hold the contents of your set.

```
std::vector<double> output(input.size());
std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin());
```

Comment: This doesn't deserve -1.  In particular, this allows vector to only do one allocation (since it can't determine the distance of set iterators  in O(1)), and, if it wasn't defined for vector to zero out each element when constructed, this could be worthwhile to allow the copy to boil down to a memcpy.  The latter could still be worthwhile if the implementation figures out the loop in vector's ctor can be removed.  Of course, the former can also be achieved with reserve.

Comment: I gave you a -1, but it was a thinko on my part. Make a small edit so I can undo my vote, and I'll give you a +1: this is actually a very clean solution because of the fail-first property.

Comment: I only just figured out that if I edit the answer myself, I can do an upvote. Did that, gave you a +1 for the fail-first memory allocation. Sorry!

Comment: Also, very important that it's not just _"reserving"_ enough space that's needed, but also initializing (default-constructing) those instance slots. So, just calling `output.reserve(input.size())` wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most efficient way is to preallocate and then emplace elements:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> VectorFromSet(const std::set<T>& from)
{
    std::vector<T> to;
    to.reserve(from.size());

    for (auto const& value : from)
        to.emplace_back(value);

    return to;
}
```

That way we will only invoke copy constructor for every element as opposed to calling default constructor first and then copy assignment operator for other solutions listed above. More clarifications below.

1. *back_inserter* may be used but it will invoke push_back() on the vector
   (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator).
   *emplace_back()* is more efficient because it avoids creating a temporary when using *push_back()*. It is not a problem with trivially
   constructed types but will be a performance implication for
   non-trivially constructed types (e.g. std::string).
2. We need to avoid constructing a vector with the size argument which
   causes all elements default constructed (for nothing). Like with
   solution using *std::copy()*, for instance.
3. And, finally, *vector::assign()* method or the constructor taking the iterator range are not good options
   because they will invoke std::distance() (to know number of elements)
   on *set* iterators. This will cause unwanted additional iteration
   through the all *set* elements because the set is Binary Search Tree
   data structure and it does not implement random access iterators.

Hope that helps.

Comment: please add a reference to an authority why this is fast and something like why a `back_inserter` doesn't need to be used

Comment: Added more clarifications in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
set<T> s;
// some code
vector<T> v;
v.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::copy` cannot be used to insert into an empty container. To do that, you need to use an insert_iterator like so:

```
std::set<double> input;
input.insert(5);
input.insert(6);

std::vector<double> output;
std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), inserter(output, output.begin()));
```

Comment: This fails the first time the vector reallocates: the iterator from output.begin() gets invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

The COPY function returns an iterator to the end of the destination range (which points to the element following the last element copied).

A back-insert iterator is a special type of output iterator designed to allow algorithms that usually overwrite elements (such as copy) to instead insert new elements automatically at the end of the container.

set os;
vector vec;

copy(os.begin(), os.end(), back_inserter(vec));