# Is there any way/trick to pass std::set to a C API which expects C Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, set

Is there is a way/trick to pass std::set to a C API which expects C Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you could fill an array with your set contents pretty quickly.  For example, assuming mySet is a set of the same type as YOUR_TYPENAME:

```
YOUR_TYPENAME arr* = new YOUR_TYPENAME[mySet.size()];
std::copy(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), arr);
```

Then just pass arr into the C API.

Comment: Why would you use `new` when you could use `vector`?

Comment: +1. I like this solution more than the `vector` one, because it does not require an intermediary type. *But*, as you are dealing with a C API I'd allocate the array with `malloc` (or a derivate), especially if the array is likely to be `free`d inside the API.

Comment: @Constantinius, I agree that `malloc` would be more appropriate than `new` if the ownership was passed to the API, but I wouldn't expect that to be a common case. Not sure what you mean by an intermediary type, in both cases you're creating an array of the element type. `vector` leaves you with fewer memory management issues, especially if there's any chance that an exception might be thrown somewhere.

Comment: @Constantinius: What does "require an intermediary type" have to do with anything? Guess what: `new YOUR_TYPENAME[...]` has a type too! `std::vector` is more appropriate. The question says nothing about `free`'ing.

Comment: I prefer not to pass vectors into C functions even though it's really just contiguous memory either way (I've actually seen non-standard compliant vector implementations on some embedded OS's, so I don't like to rely on the vector being contiguous) - but I do agree malloc would be a better thing to use given we're working with C :)

Comment: @Constantinius, this is purely academic since we don't know the specifics of the API, but in general, if the API is going to free memory you allocate, it _must_ specify exactly how should you allocate it. `malloc` and `free` won't do much good if two CRTs happen to be used (and obviously, neither will `new` and `delete`). So in case of memory ownership transfer across API boundaries, there are no best practices - just strict definitions (given you can't change the API).

Answer (score 11):

Not directly, but you can first [convert the set to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034211/c-copy-set-to-vector) (called, say, `vec`), and then pass `&vec[0]`, which is a pointer to the first element of the internal vector array.

With C++11, you can pass `vec.data()` instead of `&vec[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the vector alternative to the currently accepted answer would look like this:

```
{
  std::vector<YOUR_TYPENAME> arr(mySet.begin(), mySet.end());
  Your_C_API(&arr[0]);
  // memory implicitly freed on next line
}
```

I prefer this style because:

- It takes one fewer lines, and
- It eliminates a class of mistakes that I often make (that is, forgetting to `delete`).